# Simple watermarking for power point slides

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, watermark

How would I go about performing simple watermarking on power point slides, using an image?

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, the best option would be to just do it in PowerPoint itself by adding it as an image in the master slide. Go into

> View > Master Views > Slide Master

then put the image in the slide that's at the top of the hierarchy.
That way it will be applied to every slide in the presentation.

Answer (score -1):

I add a Text image to the Master

```
View > Master Views > Slide Master
```

I add the word Draft - in a large font - with a shadow and then make it partially transparent.  I rotate the word so it's at an angle and so it really does look like a water mark.  I send it to the back of the page so all text shows over it unless I have a picture on the page then I move it up.

The key key difference is pushing the text to the back, if you have the water mark on the front it usually makes it much harder for people to review and see, and if they print they usually loose the entire text.  If you push the item to the back then the printing function still works and you can still see the words on top of the water mark.